# modifying django model forms after post

Tags: django, post

I would like to modify a user submitted form to automatically insert the project_id, but I keep getting the error that project_id in the Employee model cannot be null;

My model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_started = models.DateTimeField()

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class AddEmployeeForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = Employee
     exclude = ('project',)
```

My view:

```
def emp_add(request, project_id):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    post = request.POST.copy() # make the POST QueryDict mutable
    post('project', project_id)
    form = AddEmployeeForm(post)
    if form.is_valid():
        saved = form.save()
```

Comment: Do you mean `post['project'] = project_id` in line 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
if form.is_valid():
    employee = form.save(commit=False)
    employee.project = Project.objects.get(pk=project_id)
    employee.save()
```

Comment: yes this works.  However, I was hoping to be able to add the project_id directly to the form so that I could call is_valid() on it.  That way i can benefit from the form validation routine, and it would be one less database call.

Answer (score 3):

@maciag.artur's answer, to save with `commit=False` will work. Another way is to instantiate an Employee with the required `project_id`, and use it to construct the form.

This is useful if your model form's custom clean method relies on the Employee.project field.

```
def emp_add(request, project_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a new employee with the given project id
        employee = Employee(project_id) = project_id
        form = AddEmployeeForm(request.POST, instance=employee)
        if form.is_valid():
            saved = form.save()
        <snip>
```

For reference, see the note box below [*Using a subset of fields on the form*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) in the Django docs.

Answer (score 1):

Add the project ID to the form as a hidden input. When the request comes back as a POST, it will exist in the POST object, from the form.

```
def emp_add(request, project_id):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    post = request.POST.copy() # make the POST QueryDict mutable
    post('project', project_id)
    form = AddEmployeeForm(post)
    if form.is_valid():
        saved = form.save()
 else:
    form = AddEmployeeForm(initial={'project_id':'my_id_value'})
```